# Jacoco not excluding Lombok generated methods in Gradle build of Groovy sources

Tags: gradle, groovy, jacoco, lombok

I have a Spring boot project with multiple modules and entirely coded in Groovy. Using **Gradle 5.0** to build the project.

**Jacoco plugin (0.8.2)** is unable to *exclude getters/setters/toString* methods.
These are generated at compile time using lombok's **@Data** annotation.
Lombok is used a dependency in Gradle build script

```
compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4"
annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4"
```

I have tried with lombok.config file in root level, inner modules level, package level, resources folder. Tried so many options but jacoco still reports 0% coverage for getters/setters for Spring bean classes.

```
rootProject
    module-1
        src
            main
                groovy
                    com.foo.bar
                        lombok.config
                    lombok.config   
                lombok.config
            lombok.config
        lombok.config
    module-2
        //same thing as above
    lombok.config

Tried with lombok.config at various levels with no success
```

Contents of lombok.config file

```
config.stopBubbling = true
lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true
```

What else is needed to exclude getters/setters of groovy sources in jacoco coverage?

Comment: What version of Lombok are you using?

Comment: Lombok version is 1.18.4

Comment: Are you sure that `@lombok.Data` annotation has any effect on your Groovy class? Aren't Groovy generates getters/setters/toString methods?

Comment: Without Lombok, how do I get rid of getter/setter code coverage for groovy files? I did not see documentation under FilteringOptions of jacoco.

Comment: You need at least Groovy `2.5.3` -  https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/pull/733#issuecomment-421797478

Comment: @Godin That was it. Thanks for your response.Lombok was not needed. Migrating to groovy 2.5.4 excluded code coverage for generated getters/setters etc. Add it as an answer. I will accept it.